# How to make the C++ precompiler do a "loop"

Tags: c++, precompile

I want to simplify the following code:

```
switch (index)
    {
    case 1:
        output = function1();
        break;
    case 2:
        output = function2();
        break;
    case 3:
        output = function3();
        break;
    ....
```

Where `index` is a compile time constant.

If I would use a precompiler macro, I would need to use it `n` times, where `n` is the number of cases. How can I reduce the above mentioned code to O(1) lines of code?

Comment: Why do this and make the code less readable?

Comment: @EdHeal I was hoping there was some precompiler magic that would make the code more readable. Something like output = SOME_MAGICAL_MACRO(function, index)

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: It's not very C++-ish to use macros. Please pick the Ed Heal's answer. I'd first advice to check the code. ("Jinak se dá předávat pointer/reference na funkci i jako parametr. Bývá to mnohem lepší.")

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your advice. Actually I did it according to Ed's answer. There are times, when you do not have a choice, but to use macros. Such as when you use a library that is not C++-ish.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Oh, I see, no choice then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be supermacro can slightly simplify your work.
Simply create "counter.def" file with code:

```
COUNTER(1)
COUNTER(2)
COUNTER(3)
#undef COUNTER
```

Then in any case of using switch or any other construction with repeating counting

```
switch(index)
{
    #define COUNTER(i) case i: output = function##i(); break;
    #include "counter.def"
}
```

Comment: Oh no... please never ever do that in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (assuming function 1-n are the real names. and that index is, as you say, a compile time constant):

```
#define CALLFUNCTION(x) function##x()

output = CALLFUNCTION(1);
```

**correction**: this will not work for variables, will work if the constant is used directly. This might defeat the purpose if the provided code is all there is in each case statement.

There is no need to do a switch at all. Alternatively you could use template specialization.

```
template<int index> function();

output = function<index>();
```

and specialize the function template for each index.

```
template<> function<1>(){return 1;} // or {return function1();}
```

If it is not a compile time constant, you need to generate the switch like Fomin Arseniy suggests. Another option would be to use a array of function pointers

Comment: Thank you! One problem is that I cannot change the definition of function1, ..., functionn.

Comment: not a problem, first method will work as it is, 2nd method can be a wrapper to function1-functionn

Comment: It makes a compiler error: there are no arguments to 'functionindex' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'functionindex' must be available [-fpermissive]

Comment: you are right, the  macro method will only work if index is replaced with the number itself. Sorry for not catching it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it with a macro - but this will work (I think):

```
int (*functions[])() = { &function1, &function2, &function3};

int output = functions[index]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, since then it's useful to check boost libraries on it:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp>

#define DECL(z, n, _) case n: (function ## n)(); break;

BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(1, 3, DECL, _)
```

However, if you're in a somewhat newer C++, it's recommended to use template metaprogramming and `if constexpr ()` instead.